# PHP arrays & keys - fetching particular ones

Tags: php

Lets say I have an array with a structure like this:

```
$arr= Array(
    array(
    "id"=>"a"
    "type">"apple"),

    array(
    "id"=>"b"),

    array(
    "id"=>"c"),

    array(
    "id"=>"c"
    "type"=>"banana")
);
```

now I want to have a foreach loop which fetches all the array elements which have a key in them named "type".

Something like

```
foreach(all arrays which have type in them as $item)
```

How would I do that?

many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
   if (array_key_exists("type", $value))
     var_dump($value);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway I can get the required elements without having to traverse the entire array?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($arr as $arrsub)
{
    if(isset($arrsub['type']))
    {
       //here do your stuff
    }
}
```